# Mysql Query not returning any output?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'am using codeigniter and I'm executing this query

```
SELECT c.id AS id, c.name AS name, c.img_add AS img, c.downloads as down, c.tag as tag, c.date as date,c.views as view FROM core c WHERE c.name = 'Ganesha (2)' ORDER BY c.downloads DESC
```

The query is used in the model, and does not returns any data, while the same query when executed in the Heidi SQL, returns me with the appropriate data.

I don't know weather it is a query problem, codeigniter problem or php's, so I'm posting for all.

This is a code which I wrote in my codeigniter model. This may help in answering.

```
public function getFolderDetail($folder) {

    $sql = "SELECT c.id AS `id`, c.name AS `name`, c.img_add AS `img`, c.downloads as `down`, c.tag as `tag`, c.date as `date`,c.views as `view` FROM core c
            WHERE c.name = ?
            ORDER BY c.downloads DESC";
    $params = array($folder);
    return $query = $this->db->query($sql,$params);
}
```

Comment: Breaks are allowed in queries. ;)

Comment: I just need a reason why this query works on Heidi sql, but gives no result while fetching from PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem, actualy the value in folder for `Ganesh (2)` was coming as `Ganesha &#40;2&#41;` which is a url format of the value, as I am sending this value as urls.

I did this

```
public function getFolderDetail($folder) {
$folder = str_replace('&#41;',')',$folder);
$folder = str_replace('&#40;','(',$folder);
    //echo $folder = str_replace('(','\(',$folder);

    $sql = "SELECT c.id AS `id`, c.name AS `name`, c.img_add AS `img`, c.downloads as `down`, c.tag as `tag`, c.date as `date`,c.views as `view` FROM core c
            WHERE c.name = ?
            ORDER BY c.downloads DESC";
    $params = array($folder);
    return $query = $this->db->query($sql,$params);
}
```

and now the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion may be reserved words, and may need `tick` marks around them.  I would start with your

```
 `name`, `date` and `view` columns...
```

the tick is the ` key left of the #1 on keyboard, not a single quote

each part that may be reserved would need the tick marks... such as

```
c.`name` as `name` (same with others)
```

it would be applicable in the where clause to

```
where c.`name` = 'something'
```

ARE YOU running into an invalid function?

By sending in the string you mention of "Alexa (2)", might it be interpreting that as a FUNCTION called "Alexa", and it is passing a parameter of 2, and thus Alexa is not a real function.  Can you try by NOT having parens as the value?

[Here is a list of MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: i have used the escape letter yet no luck, I also stated in my question that this query is working on Heidi Sql, a query browser for desktop, yet fetches me no result when called as a query from php.

Comment: @KCloud, did you `tick` wrap each of the possible reserved words (name, date, view and maybe even tag)... such would be written as c.`name` as `name` (same with others)  it would be applicable in the where clause too.

Comment: i tick wrap everything all the names, now for better explanation when i send '(' or ')' to the query it doesn't executes else it works fine...for eg. in the code above replace the ? with 'Alexa' the code goes fine, replace it with 'Alexa (2)' the code result with nothing found.

Comment: @KCloud, see revision... it is falsely interpreting Alexa(2) as a FUNCTION CALL?

Comment: Thanks, for your help, but things got sorted out, I even posted a response of this question you can look below. Thank you again.

Comment: @KCloud I guess I was close... it was based on the parens :), but different that I could not obviously see in your output stream.

Comment: actually the problem wasn't the query it was the codeigniter, whenever we push a value in codeigniter function, it sends that value to headers, and urlencodes that, this was creating the problem, yet I don't know why it wasn't decoding it other end so I decoded it myself. Secondly if the `tick` was a problem it shouldn't have executed in `Heidi SQL`, but it did. Rather, thanks for the suggestion I'll remember those.

Answer (score 0):

try to escape reserved word "date"

```
SELECT `c`.`date` as `date` etc...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html